# The pipe 'can' could not be found

Tags: javascript, angular, casl

I am trying to implement [CASL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@casl/angular) ability manager for my `angular 8` app. I did everything that described in the package usage guide but there is an error about `can pipe` in my `component html template`.

```
The pipe 'can' could not be found
```

So here is my app module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
...
        AbilityModule.forRoot()
    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [
...
        { provide: Ability, useFactory: createAbility }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I implemented like [this casl example](https://codesandbox.io/s/6y325ml5vk) also.

`createAbility` function is shown  below:

```
import { AbilityBuilder, Ability } from '@casl/ability'
import { User, Claim } from '@/_models';
import { ABILITIES } from './const-variables';

var user = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
var currentUser = JSON.parse(user) as User;

export function defineAbilitiesFor(user: User) {
  const { can, rules } = AbilityBuilder.extract();

  if (user.roles.includes("Admin")) {
    can("manage", "all");
  } else {
    user.claims.forEach(claim => {
      ABILITIES.map(ability => {
        if (ability.name === (claim as Claim).type) {
          can(ability.name, ability.module);
        }
      })
    });
  }
  return rules;
}

export function createAbility() {
  return new Ability(defineAbilitiesFor(currentUser), {
    subjectName(subject) {
      if (!subject || typeof subject === "string") {
        return subject;
      }
      return subject.__typename;
    }
  });
}
```

I would tell also it works in my component class with `this.ability.can()` by injecting `Ability` class.But it can't work with `can pipe`

What should I do for getting rid of this error?

Thanks

Comment: can you show your createAbility factory?

Comment: Try to look at https://github.com/stalniy/casl-angular-example .

Comment: what versions of casl/angular and casl/ability do you use?

Comment: I also faced this problem in angular 10, for me it was related to import of AbilityModule into the custom module. Now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created your ability? I see you've defined useFactory: createAbility but from the docs the example is:

```
import { AbilityBuilder } from '@casl/ability'

export const ability = AbilityBuilder.define(can => {
   can('read', 'all')
})
```

What happens if you change that to useValue and build your definition based on the example?